# If $ \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx $ converges. What can be said about $ \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x^2) \,dx $?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Given a function $f$ that it is non-negative and continuous in $[1,\infty]$.

If $ \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx $ converges, does $ \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x^2) \,dx $ also converge?

I think the statement is true but cannot justify it.
I was trying to use the comparison test but couldn't find a function to compare to.

Any idea?

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty f(x^2)\,dx = \int_1^\infty f(t)\, \frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}$.

Comment: Note $|f(t)|\gt |\frac{f(t)}{2\sqrt{t}}|$ for $t\ge 1$

Comment: Thanks. Got it.